# who call an activity with flag_activity_new_task

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity A (main Activity) that is called from an BroadCasterReciever B when device reboot

```
Intent i = new Intent (context,activityA.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

I'd like to do something like that in Activity A:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (called from B) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

putExtra and getExtra doesn't work

Comment: "Who" or "why"? That makes the difference between a good question and an opinion based question

Comment: well I've just tried with getIntExtra and it works, but not with boolean

Comment: See the title; Do you mean "Who" or "Why"? If who, this is opinion based question

Comment: `putExtra` and `getXExtra` works. Show us your attempt.

Comment: I was trying with
 i.putExtra("reiniciado","true");
and
boolean reiniciado = this.getIntent().getBooleanExtra("reiniciado",false);
and always get false

Comment: ups !! I got it. It's true instead "true". Thanks everybody

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Store data in sharedpref and check called from broadcast or normal

[Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)